# How can I delete multiple DIV ids all at once with console?

Tags: javascript, console

anyone knows how can i delete multiple div IDs all at once with a command in console? Thanks

Comment: var element = document.getElementById("ELEMENT");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);


this will only delete one element for me, but I need multiple at once, anyone knows, please?

Comment: Do you multiple elements with the same id by any chance? That would be invalid HTML if you do. If they are all different, do you have a list of id values you want to type into the console?

Comment: No, all Id's are different

Answer (score 0):

You can remove an element using [`Element.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove). Just call that method on each element that you want to remove.

For selecting multiple elements, you can use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) which [matches the elements that you are targeting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors).

```js
// You didn't show in your question which elements
// you want to select, so here's an example:
function getElements () {
 return document.querySelectorAll('li.even');
}

function removeEven () {
  const elements = getElements();

  for (const element of elements) {
    element.remove();
  }
}

const button = document.querySelector('button.remove');

button.addEventListener('click', removeEven);
```

```html
<div>
  <ol>
    <li class="odd">A</li>
    <li class="even">B</li>
    <li class="odd">C</li>
    <li class="even">D</li>
  </ol>  
</div>
<div>
  <button class="remove">Remove even elements</button>
</div>
```

---

Update in response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73048705/how-can-i-delete-multiple-div-ids-all-at-once-with-console/73048904?noredirect=1#comment129017202_73048904):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#id-a, #id-b, #id-c').forEach(elm => elm.remove());
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that is really cool. But I just need to remove line with specific DIV id's in same command. If that is possible?

Comment: @Harry See update

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a quoted, comma separated list of id values. Add a call to `split` at the commas, followed by a `forEach` clause to remove the elements. If you're like me and throw in spaces as well, `trim` the id value as well.

E.G. to delete divs with ids divA, divB, divC, mydiv, yourDiv, theirDiv, execute

```
"divA, divB, divC, myDiv, yourDiv, theirDiv".split(',').forEach( id=>document.getElementById(id.trim()).remove() )
```

on the console. If you do it often, keep most of the text separately.